# Console.WriteLine sends output to debug in vs.net, but when run from console, I see nothing

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, windows-services, stdout

I have a C# windows service.  In that service code, I define Main() and capture various arguments.  If the arg is "install" I call code to install the service.  Note that when the arg is install, I am not running the service, just installing it, so it seems to me that this is nothing more than a console app at that point.

When I debug the code in vs.net 2012, I see all of my Console.WriteLine() output in the debug window.  I believe that is because VS.NET maps STDOUT to the debug window.

But if I open a command prompt and run the command line `myservice.exe install`, there is no output to the console window.  If I run `myservice.exe install > out.txt` I see all of the output in out.txt.  What happened and how can I get that Main() code to actually send the output to the console window?

Comment: Err... isn't the whole point of `> out.txt` to redirect output to the file? What happens if you just execute `myservice.exe install`?

Comment: Consider to use *log4net*, *nlog* or other logging framework to easily switch output

Comment: slolife from my experience please check your project settings in VS2012. My feeling is that you might have there checked option which disable `console` view.

Comment: Yes, `> out.txt` does go to the file, but if I don't add that, there is no output in the console.

Comment: Please let me know where the `disable console view` option is, I don't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be due to the Output Type of your project; please note that the default Windows Application output type does not automatically show a console window.
For this, you may want to change the Output Type to a Console Application.

Comment: Okay, that did the trick.  I'd like a little more info about what changes when I move my windows service project from a windows app to a console app?  Does a windows service app need to be a Windows App?  Note that I wasn't launch the exe by double clicking or anything.  I was in a console and typed in the command line.  I thought that any Console.WriteLine() calls would go to the console or STDOUT.  How can I programatically change that?

Comment: Afaik, moving to a console application will just set a flag in the PE header of your assembly, which will instruct the loader to create and attach the process to the standard streams upon load. A Windows service does NOT need to be a Windows application.

Comment: There is also a [trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7827950/904178) which basically uses a couple of Win32 APIs to attach to a console window, even for non-console applications, but I would stay away if possible.