# Running program in background from command line

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application

So I have a console application that runs a command line process and then closes. For that second that the process gets called, I can see the window of the process pop up then disappear.

Is it possible to either:

- Run the other process in the background
- Run the other process minimized so that it still shows on the taskbar but not on the screen.

**My code currently:**

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.Start();

proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Navigate to Correct Folder");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Run Outside Program");
```

Comment: But doesn't that mean it will create a window?

Comment: Yep you have to set it to true to not show a Window

Comment: Gotcha.... sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Add that line :
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c;

And that one :
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Add that line :

```
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c;
```

And that one :

```
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Hm, after adding those two lines of code it doesn't launch the other process at all.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy Oh, maybe it is my string that is incorrect. Use this : "/c" instead of " /c".

Comment: Still no luck, I'm not sure I can control the behavior of this outside program.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're actually seeing the window of your console application, and not the process you're launching. Change the output type to Windows Application.[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15079092/3845456)'s a solution that will allow you to show the console still if you need to, for example, if something goes wrong and you want to alert the user.