# How to Change Application Output Type During Runtime

Tags: c#, command-line, visual-studio-2015, output

I am trying to add command-line support for a desktop application I built so that I can run its commands from elsewhere without display the UI. This is approximately what my `Main` method looks like:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Run the desktop application
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnProcessExit;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var mainForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
        mainForm.BringToFront();
    }
    // Restart the session and log in console
    else if(args[0] == "restartsession")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Restarting session...");
    }
    // argument not recognised (log to console)
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Argument \"{args[0]}\" not recognised");
    }
}
```

This appears to work just fine, apart from the fact that the Console window is not displayed when calling `Console.WriteLine()`.

This is due to my project's output type being set to `Windows Application` (I set this in properties). If I change it to `Console Application` the console window appears with my logging, but then it also displays when opening the "UI" desktop version (ie running the app without any arguments).

Is there a way to change the output type depending on the arguments passed into `Main()`? For example something like this perhaps:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Application.OutputType = WindowsApplication
    }
    else if(args[0] == "restartsession")
    {
        Application.OutputType = ConsoleApplication
    }
}
```

I was able to find [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984569(v=vs.71).aspx) but it appears to be old and not relevant any more. Is there some other way of achieving this?

Comment: no, you will have to build 2 exe's with either type.

Comment: @leppie Thanks for your comment leppie. Is this standard practice for creating exes with commandline support? I ask because we would prefer 2 have just 1 application due to space constraints.

Comment: You only need to 2 small (4KB at most) exe's and a big dll.

Comment: In Windows, the PE format (used for executables) only allows one subsystem type. In this case, that is *either* a Windows application or a Console application. You have to pick one, you cannot have both. However, [a Windows application can allocate and display a console window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application) on-demand. Or you can just create your own window with a textbox/richtextbox/listview/etc. and treat it like a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leppie has the right answer in the comments. For scenarios like this, your actual application project should be *very* small. It should include only things that are specific to that application type.

All of your business logic, application shared initialization logic, etc. should be moved to a different project which is consumed by both.

Answer (score 0):

As Leppie suggested in a comment, this is not possible and I will have to build 2 separate applications - one for the desktop and one for the command-line.

A possible solution for this would be to compartmentalise the `RestartSession` functions into a `dll` and then have 2 small exes calling the same dll (one for the desktop and one for the console)