# Winform logging when Started from CMD

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I have a Winform application that can be started normally by double-clicking on it and using as a foreground windows application, also it can be started from the command line with arguments

What I need is to allow the application `Console.WriteLine` function logs to be printed to the command line.

Currently, when I start the application from the command line, it just executes and the cursor goes to a new line as if it is ready to take new command. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I tried checking the answers under the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application/472432#472432) (which neither of them worked for me)

Comment: @Sinatr as they suggested when using `AllocConsole` and other ones it is only opening a new console window, but no logs are showing

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `AttachConsole`. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/472432/1997232) looks interesting too.

Comment: @Sinatr so you didn't see my comment on his answer right? hehehe

Comment: @Sinatr I found the answer: using the answer link you provided plus `kernel32.dll` `FreeConsole` function, I had to read the documentation of `kernel32.dll` in order to understand its functions and to know how to really use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading the documentation for `kernel32.dll` and making some tests

I reached to the following solution

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/472432/1997232) plus the function `FreeConsole` from `kernel32.dll` in order to make it work

First I made my WinForm application to run as a console application **project properties** > **Application** > **Output type** = **Console Application**

This will allow the project to run as a console application so when starting the application normally (double click exe or run from visual studio), it would start the windows application and would start a cmd window

To fix this I had to use the function `FreeConsole` from `kernel32.dll` in order to release the cmd window

The resulted working script I ended with is

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            FreeConsole();
            MessageBox.Show("Application running by double-clicking on exe");

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FrmMain());
        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application is running from cmd with arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** The above snippet will remove the console windows from the application, which will release the handler of the `Console`, meaning when calling `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.Write` functions it will throw an exception `The handle is invalid`

To avoid this problem, we don't need to release the console window completely, it is enough to hide it, as below using `ShowWindow` from `kernel32.dll`

In the `program` class

```
//[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
//private static extern bool FreeConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

And in the `Main` function

```
//FreeConsole();
var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, 0);
```